# Zxing Scanner in a Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, zxing

I'm trying to make a QR Code Scanner in my application using Zxing Scanner. However, i'm using **fragment** instead of activity. What parameter should i put to     mScannerView.setResultHandler(??????).

My Button to go to QR Code Scanner

```
FloatingActionButton add = (FloatingActionButton) view.findViewById(R.id.add_friend);
    add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {                
            mScannerView = new ZXingScannerView(getActivity());
            getActivity().setContentView(mScannerView);
            mScannerView.setResultHandler(??????);
            mScannerView.startCamera();
        }
    });
```

**There is error when i use getActivity() and getContext()**.Kindly Help me..Thanks.

Comment: What type of parameter does the method require?

Answer (score 1):

```
mScannerView.setResultHandler(new ZXingScannerView.ResultHandler() {
            @Override
            public void handleResult(Result rawResult) {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Contents = " + rawResult.getText() + ", Format = " + rawResult.getBarcodeFormat().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
});
```

or just implement it

```
public class ScannerFragment extends BaseFragment implements ZXingScannerView.ResultHandler {

    @Override
    public void handleResult(Result rawResult) {
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Contents = " + rawResult.getText() + ", Format = " + rawResult.getBarcodeFormat().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

}
```